# Como quitar las sombras que quedan por detrás de un contenedor que posee opacity y position absolute

Tags: html, css

Quisiera quitar el contenido que queda sombreado por detrás de un contenedor principal, que posee posición absoluta y opacidad.

Me gustaría que quedase solo el fondo establecido con un background especifico, y así, solo permanece el contenido del contenedor principal que se encuentra por adelante.

Comparto una foto, donde el texto que queda por atrás de lo marcado con celeste es lo que quiero que se quite, y que quede el fondo blanco únicamente.

Desde ya, muchas gracias por su atención!

[image: Pagina donde muestro mi problema]

Comparto el código

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #222;
    opacity: .9;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 40;
}
.contain {
    background: #fff;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 66%;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 66%;
}
.text-color {
    font-size: 35px;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="contain">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem, beatae minus. Autem aut totam recusandae
                porro libero, voluptas deserunt quas tenetur, vitae laboriosam sit blanditiis. Recusandae, commodi.
                Ducimus, error ab.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem, beatae minus. Autem aut totam recusandae
                porro libero, voluptas deserunt quas tenetur, vitae laboriosam sit blanditiis. Recusandae, commodi.
                Ducimus, error ab.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem, beatae minus. Autem aut totam recusandae
                porro libero, voluptas deserunt quas tenetur, vitae laboriosam sit blanditiis. Recusandae, commodi.
                Ducimus, error ab.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p class="text-color">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa necessitatibus possimus
        porro recusandae dignissimos minus iure vel repellat asperiores fugit, velit et quidem obcaecati sed quia
        facere! Possimus, consequuntur dolore!</p>
    <p class="text-color">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa necessitatibus possimus
        porro recusandae dignissimos minus iure vel repellat asperiores fugit, velit et quidem obcaecati sed quia
        facere! Possimus, consequuntur dolore!</p>
    <p class="text-color">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa necessitatibus possimus
        porro recusandae dignissimos minus iure vel repellat asperiores fugit, velit et quidem obcaecati sed quia
        facere! Possimus, consequuntur dolore!</p>
    <p class="text-color">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa necessitatibus possimus
        porro recusandae dignissimos minus iure vel repellat asperiores fugit, velit et quidem obcaecati sed quia
        facere! Possimus, consequuntur dolore!</p>
    <p class="text-color">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa necessitatibus possimus
        porro recusandae dignissimos minus iure vel repellat asperiores fugit, velit et quidem obcaecati sed quia
        facere! Possimus, consequuntur dolore!</p>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Por qué no simplemente pones un color RGBA de fondo y quitas la propiedad de opacidad?

Para ello puedes utilizar `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);`

```
.container {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;

background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);

position: absolute;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
z-index: 40;
```

}

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 40;
}
.contain {
    background: #fff;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 66%;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 66%;
}
.text-color {
    font-size: 35px;
    color: red;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="contain">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem, beatae minus. Autem aut totam recusandae
                porro libero, voluptas deserunt quas tenetur, vitae laboriosam sit blanditiis. Recusandae, commodi.
                Ducimus, error ab.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem, beatae minus. Autem aut totam recusandae
                porro libero, voluptas deserunt quas tenetur, vitae laboriosam sit blanditiis. Recusandae, commodi.
                Ducimus, error ab.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem, beatae minus. Autem aut totam recusandae
                porro libero, voluptas deserunt quas tenetur, vitae laboriosam sit blanditiis. Recusandae, commodi.
                Ducimus, error ab.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p class="text-color">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa necessitatibus possimus
        porro recusandae dignissimos minus iure vel repellat asperiores fugit, velit et quidem obcaecati sed quia
        facere! Possimus, consequuntur dolore!</p>
    <p class="text-color">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa necessitatibus possimus
        porro recusandae dignissimos minus iure vel repellat asperiores fugit, velit et quidem obcaecati sed quia
        facere! Possimus, consequuntur dolore!</p>
    <p class="text-color">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa necessitatibus possimus
        porro recusandae dignissimos minus iure vel repellat asperiores fugit, velit et quidem obcaecati sed quia
        facere! Possimus, consequuntur dolore!</p>
    <p class="text-color">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa necessitatibus possimus
        porro recusandae dignissimos minus iure vel repellat asperiores fugit, velit et quidem obcaecati sed quia
        facere! Possimus, consequuntur dolore!</p>
    <p class="text-color">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa necessitatibus possimus
        porro recusandae dignissimos minus iure vel repellat asperiores fugit, velit et quidem obcaecati sed quia
        facere! Possimus, consequuntur dolore!</p>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay una opacidad de .9 en el elemento `.container`, por lo tanto, se verá el fondo ya que estás dejando ver el otro 10%.

Para que no se vea el contenido de atrás debes ponerle al elemento una opacidad de 1

```
.container {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario Brahim! pero la idea es que la opacidad del container permanezca y que se quite la opacidad del contain.